# SQL - Using sub queries to join 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, subquery

For shown database on image:
[image]

Using sub queries, what SQL statement that will return the name of employees, days worked, and the hours worked for each day.

My query so far is:

```
select E.name as Name, C.dayid as Day_Worked, P.hoursworked as Hours_Worked
from employeepaysummary P
join employee E on P.employeeid = E.employeeid
join calendarday C on P.dayid = C.dayid ;
```

I am stuck on this part: "The query should return 0 for employees who did not work for any particular day from 1st Jan – 15th Jan"

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Start by using different joins appropriately - FULL OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `OUTER JOIN` :

```
SELECT E.name as Name, d.dayid as Day_Worked, P.hoursworked as Hours_Worked
FROM calendarday d LEFT JOIN
     employeepaysummary p
     on p.dayid = d.dayid LEFT JOIN
     employee e
     on e.employeeid = e.employeeid;
```